# C calling function on contents of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, sdl, glib

I am using GLib to manage a linked list. I am declaring 2 structs and the placing them in a linked list as follows.

```
Asteroid asteroid = {0,0,50,50,50}
Asteroid asteroids = {0,0,200,200,50};

GList *asteroidList = NULL;
asteroidList = g_list_append(asteroidList, &asteroid);
asteroidList = g_list_append(asteroidList, &asteroids);
```

Then i use the following function to traverse the list and calla function that draws the struct to the screen as a circle as follows

```
void drawAsteroids(){
GList *list = asteroidList;
while(list != NULL){
    printf("Asteroids");
    GList *next = list->next;
    drawAsteroid(list->data);
    list = next;
  }
}
```

The drawing function is

```
void drawAsteroid(void *asteroid){
    Asteroid *newAsteroid = (Asteroid *)asteroid;
    printf("%d\n", newAsteroid->xPos);
    circleRGBA(renderer, newAsteroid->xPos, newAsteroid->yPos, newAsteroid->r, 0, 255, 0, 255);
}
```

The struct is defined as follows

```
typedef struct asteroid{
    int xSpeed;
    int ySpeed;

    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    int r;
}Asteroid;
```

When i run this code i dont see anything drawn to the screen

Comment: Following this [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436335/c-struct-member-problems) but still no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and still using duplicate variable names.

Comment: This feels suspiciously like the first question...

Comment: i migrated the linked list to Glib instead of the first library i was using and created my own function to traverse the list and call the function on the contents of the list. Is anymore information needed?

Comment: Read the link about the MCVE. Your example is not complete. It's likely the two `Asteroid` variables on the stack need to be allocated on the heap, but we can't tell without seeing a minimal but compilable program.

Answer (score 0):

The `GList` functions do *not* copy the data. If you place the `Asteroid` structure on the stack, and it goes out of scope, then the `list->data` pointer will point to garbage.

You need to allocate the data on the heap, and then remember to free it when not needed any more.