# c linked list drawing struct to the screen

Tags: c, linked-list, sdl, glib

I have a game that instantiates a new struct every 40 frames and adds it to a linked list. It then loops through the linked list drawing each struct to the screen as a circle using SDL.However, the circles are drawn to the screen and then disappear again rather than staying on the screen.

This function makes the new struct and is called every 40 frames

```
void spawnAsteroid(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int maxRad = 60;
  int minRad = 20;
  Asteroid asteroidddd = {0,0,rand()%SCREEN_WIDTH , rand()%SCREEN_HEIGHT, (rand()%(maxRad-minRad))+minRad};
  asteroidList = g_list_prepend(asteroidList, &asteroidddd);
}
```

This one loops through the linked list

```
void drawAsteroids(){
GList *list = asteroidList;
//loop through the list
while(list != NULL){
    GList *next = list->next;
    //draw each asteroid
    drawAsteroid(list->data);
    list = next;
}
}
```

This function draws the struct as a circle

```
void drawAsteroid(void *asteroid){
//cast the void pointer so it can be dereferenced
Asteroid *newAsteroid = (Asteroid *)asteroid;
circleRGBA(renderer, newAsteroid->xPos, newAsteroid->yPos, newAsteroid->r, 0, 255, 0, 255);
}
```

Now i give the structs an x speed and a y speed. Then i loop through the list again and update the position variables by the speed varibales so the circles slowly move across the screen. However no movement is seen.

This function loops through the list

```
  void updateAsteroids(){
    GList *list = asteroidList;
    //loop through the list
    while(list != NULL){
        GList *next = list->next;
        //draw each asteroid
        updateAsteroid(list->data);
        list = next;
    }
}
```

This function then updates the position

```
void updateAsteroid(void *asteroid){
    //cast so it can be dereferenced
    Asteroid *newAsteroid = (Asteroid *)asteroid;
    newAsteroid -> xPos += newAsteroid -> xSpeed / 60;
    newAsteroid -> yPos += newAsteroid -> ySpeed / 60;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C calling function on contents of linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441064/c-calling-function-on-contents-of-linked-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a pointer to a *local variable* to your list. Local variables go out of scope and disappear once the function returns.

That means you have a list of pointers to non-existing objects and will have *undefined behavior* every time you dereference those pointers.

You need to allocated the structures *dynamically* of the heap using `malloc`. And remember to `free` the nodes once you're done with them.

---

On an unrelated note you reset the random number generator in each call to `spawnAsteroid`. If you call it twice in a single second you will have two calls using the same random number sequence. Call `srand` ***once*** at the beginning of the program.

Comment: I have updated the question with a further problem. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem seams to be with the line

```
Asteroid asteroidddd = {0,0,rand()%SCREEN_WIDTH , rand()%SCREEN_HEIGHT, (rand()%(maxRad-minRad))+minRad};
```

Since no memory is allocated, asteroidddd will be destroyed once it's out of the scope of spawnAsteroid().

You should instead do:

```
Asteroid *asteroidddd = malloc(sizeof(Asteroid));
// Populate properties..
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a further problem. Any help would be appreciated